# How to make an element stay on nth cell using grid layout?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a responsive grid layout, the columns and rows are calculated dynamically by the window's size.

Now I want the `.target` to be on a specific cell regardless of the grid columns, let's say the 7th cell, so if the grid has 5 columns, the `.target` should be on the row 2 and column 2. Is this possible to do it?

I know I can use `grid-row` and `grid-column` to assign the position of an element. But the grid rows and columns are dynamic, so I wouldn't know which row and column is the 7th cell.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(100px, 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}

/* this need to be on the 7th cell */
.target {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <span class="target"></span>
</div>
```

I could create a lot of empty elements to push the `.target` on to the 7th cell, but I'm not allowed to touch the html structure so I can't do this:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(100px, 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}

.target {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span class="target"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Further clarification ascertained that there is always only one cell in the grid and it is to be positioned as the 7th cell.

This can be done by pure CSS if the grid is covering the width of the viewport. In this special case media queries determine at which row and column the target cell is to be.

```css
          .grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(100px, 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}

.target {
  /* there will be at least 7 cells per row */
  grid-column: 7;
  grid-row: 1;
  background-color: red;
}

@media (max-width: 699px) {
  /* 6 cells in the first row ^/
  .target {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 2;
  }
  @media (max-width: 599px) { /* 5 cells per row */
  .target {
    grid-column: 2;
    grid-row: 2;
  }
  @media (max-width: 499px) {
    /* 4 cells per row */
    .target {
      grid-column: 3;
      grid-row: 2;
    }
    @media (max-width: 399px) {
      /* 3 cells per row */
      .target {
        grid-column: 1;
        grid-row: 3;
      }
      @media (max-width: 299px) {
        /* 2 cells per row */
        .target {
          grid-column: 1;
          grid-row: 4;
        }
        @media (max-width: 199px) {
          /* 1 cell per row */
          .target {
            grid-column: 1;
            grid-row: 7;
          }
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <span class="target">target cell</span>
</div>
```

ORIGINAL ANSWER: which assumes the 'normal' case of there being children in the grid.

If there are fewer than 7 children in the grid then there won't be a 7th cell.

However if there are 7 or more direct children in the grid then you should be able to target the 7th one as a child using

```
.grid :nth-child(7) {background-color: red;}
```

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(100px, 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}

.grid span {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
}

.grid :nth-child(7) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

I may have misunderstood though - what is supposed to happen if there are less than 7 cells?

Comment: I want the element to be on the position of 7th cell as if there are 6 elements before it even there’re none :/

Comment: In the case for example where there are no cells at all what do you want to happen? In the case where there are less that 7 cells what do you want to happen with the intervening space - is it to be part of the parent grid but otherwise empty?

Comment: There is always only one child in the grid layout, the goal I want to achieve is to place it in an arbitrary cell.

Comment: Ah! I think I've finally understood, thanks. Not sure this can be done without calculation due to the minmax but I'll ponder.